# Do we need seperate file path for window and linux in java

Tags: java, io, java-server

I have a file on linux ubuntu server hosted with path name **/home/kishor/project/detail/**.
When I made a web app in window to upload and download file from specified location i used path **"c:\kishor\projects\detail\"** for saving in window.

For my surprise when i used window file path name in my server i am still able to get files and upload them, i.e, **"c:\kishor\projects\detail\"**.

Can anyone explain why it is working (as window and linux both use different file path pattern).

Comment: Are you specifying the path relatively?

Comment: No, When we add "/" in linux it refer to root and on window i have mention the drive letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this work too. What linux does is create a file whose name is literally `c:\kishor\projects\detail\`

Comment: funny HEHE. strange strange loonix.

Comment: @PrototypeStark Why is that strange? `c:\kishor\projects\detail\ ` is a valid filename.

Comment: its a valid file name alright. But use of special characters shouldn't be allowed. Don't you think? Especially ':', '{' etc. Just a thought.

Comment: @PrototypeStark Windows allows `{` and `}` as well (among others).

Comment: Thanks for this it also took me a while to find those files in server.

Answer (score 0):

If you say, you can "upload" files... perhaps there is now a new folder structure.

Some months ago i saw a similar thing: Under /home/webadmin was an new structure "/c:/Users/...."